# Handle External authentication flow with Spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflow

I have a Java application with Spring boot and Spring Webflow. Now What I want to achieve here is during webflow I need to redirect User to external source for authentication and when authentication is done user will be redirect back to my website and resume the flow in webflow from next action-state. is this possible to handle in a single webflow? If yes how. And if No what would be the ideal way to do that.